# What exactly is a "connected ring"?

Tags: postgis

I am using a PostGIS function ([`ST_StraightSkeleton`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_StraightSkeleton.html) to be exact) and I am getting an error with my data that reads:

`ERROR:  Intersection does not support polygon with connected rings`

I understand what rings are, and my data does indeed have holes, but I don't think this is the problem because [this process](https://gwmap.s3.amazonaws.com/www/presentations/WyGEO-Casper-2015.pdf) uses the same function on a dataset with holes.

I don't understand what a "connected ring" is and Google is failing me. Can someone explain it? I need to find a way to remove them from my dataset apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that inner ring touches outer ring at one vertex. Or inner rings touch each other. They are valid polygons but the error message does not claim otherwise, just that this function does not support such polygons. You can make a test with this query:

```
select ST_StraightSkeleton(
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 310 560, 990 480, 850 120, 290 120, 130 380, 310 560 ), ( 130 380, 290 290, 290 440, 130 380 ))')
);
```

I could not make the test myself because my PostGIS is missing the function. I could test that this limitation does not affect ST_Intersection and this works OK:

```
select st_intersection(
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 310 560, 990 480, 850 120, 290 120, 130 380, 310 560 ), ( 130 380, 290 290, 290 440, 130 380 ))'),
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 110 590, 370 270, 480 570, 110 590 ))'));
```